# Creating a simple mobile app with php

Tags: php, rest

Could any one suggest a tutorial or a best approach to pass and get json data using php from and to mobile app url created using android

It like I would prefer something like a php rest api  that will do the job easily and simpler.

Comment: PHP is a serverside HTTP framework. Mobile apps are built with client languages like Java (Android), C# (winphone), or ObjectiveC (ios). You might also be asking how to build a responsive interface (which is a webpage that works well on both desktop and mobile), but it's not clear what exactly you're asking.

If you just want a product suggestion, you should google for said tutorials. StackOverflow is for specific, well-researched technical questions, not broad recommendations.

Comment: but my job is to create a php pages which can fetch and send json data back to may be android based on the url the android section calls . I hope you may understand it.

Comment: If you had understood what my need is perhaps atleast you could suggest how to better ask that question :)

Comment: If you use a RESTful API your backend can be anything. PHP is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Knetic mentioned, PHP has no relation to devices, being a server-side web language.

If you want to create an android mobile app, consider Java. Or Objective C for Apple devices.

In case you want to make a web-service available for mobile devices, there's no difference on the PHP side between working with a mobile and desktop device, so you can use any PHP manual you like.

Probably it's not the best idea to start programming with REST API as it might be a little complex, but it is a great thing to use indeed. I would suggest starting from here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/

Comment: Thanks I am not beginner in php, but no idea on how to come up with an apt solution for this particular requirement :)